# navigator.navigate won't pass parameters back to previous screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my application, there is the following navigation flow happening:

Screen1 -> Screen2 -> Screen3 -> Screen2

From Screen1 -> Screen2 I am passing the parameter `{name: 'Name1'}`.

And, when navigating back to Screen2 in the last step, I am passing the parameter `{name: 'Name2'}`, however when I read the parameter `route.params.name` at the end of the flow, in Screen2, `name` equals to `Name1` rather than `Name2`.

Any ideas?

**Update**
Here's the code from Screen3 -> Screen2:

`navigation.navigate("Screen2", { name: 'Name2' });`

Comment: Can you include the code for Screen3 -> Screen2 `navigate`?

Comment: @giotskhada I have added the code

Comment: For such a case you can use stack navigator.